# web application on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat, jboss

I am planning to build a web application using eclipse and tomcat and this application would contain below features.
1. New user sign up/Existing user sign in(Session management)
2. User would be able to save some data using forms(Database connection)
Could you please let me know how good tomcat is for such application or I should use jboss?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your needs, Tomcat and JBoss are similar enough that it doesn't matter which one you go with. Just select the one with the clearest documentation/tutorials in your eyes.

Comment: Arguable, though I tend to agree.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is light weight server than Jboss and easy to learn.
It also depends on which framework you will be using .
For only servlet container , tomcat is best .

Comment: Yeah then Tomcat will be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

**JBoss is bundled with the fork version of Tomcat. So JBoss inherently contains Tomcat.** 
And coming to lightweight, Tomcat is light weight and JBoss can be configured to work as lightweight container.

You should select based on your application requirements. If you dont need any Application server features you can go with Tomcat.